# Any reason why you should not call a getter method repeatedly?

Tags: java

I'm a junior programmer in our company and I'd like to know your opinion with regards to a review point from my senior.

According to my senior, "I'm calling the `i.getName()` repeatedly" (please see my sample code below - not the actual code in our application).

I'm not sure what his concern about as I don't think it is expensive calling this simple getter method - even multiple times. It simply accessing the data from the field, no other logic being executed.

Do you think he suggests to assign the value to a local variable? e.g.: String name = i.getName(); (which I think is more not efficient).

Can you think of any reason why his remark is like that?

```
public class Item {
    private String name;

    public String getName { return name; }
}

public class Utilities {

    public String processItem(Item i) {

        if (i.getName() != null) {

            switch (i.getName())
                case: "Item1"
            ...
            ...
            
            if (i.getName().contains("_")) {
                // do some logic
            }
        }

        return "some value";
    }
}
```

Comment: What happened when you asked your "senior" for their rationale for the criticism?

Comment: You should benchmark your application in order to get realistic performances

Comment: The JVM *should* optimize this situation, I would think. It sort of looks like a "bike shedding" discussion to me

Comment: i just don't understand why he doesn't like calling the getter method multiple times. It's just a plain simple method that returns the value of the field.

Comment: Probably splitting hairs. You are probably well off by renaming the variable from `i` to something more meaningful. Now, the remark is valid if the scope is different.

Comment: I would think he is just trying to create better habits, even though it seems like nitpicking here. It's just a simple getter in this case, but in another case it could be some other function that is more inefficient. Also, one argument is that your "Utilities"-class shouldn't really assume how efficient the `getName` function is (encapsulation). In theory, nothing is stopping anyone from passing a subclass of `Item` to your `processItem` method with a much more inefficient implementation of `getItem`.

Comment: @marstran, good point

Answer (score 2):

It might help in readability of the code if you assign i.getName() to a local variable instead of calling it repeatedly. Performance wise, both will be same. Java compilers will create same optimized bytecode for both cases.